# Sharing session from parent to child

Tags: python-3.x, oop, python-requests

I have a parent class which contains a session and also some API endpoints.
The class looks like this:

```
class pdAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.api = {
            'home': 'https://example.com',
            'members': 'https://members.example.com',
            'login': 'https://example.com/login',
            'account': 'https://example.com/account',
            'videos': 'https://example.com/videos/'
        }
        self.headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'
        }
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.videos = []


    def login(self):
        payload = {'LoginFormFrontend[username]': self.username,
                   'LoginFormFrontend[password]': self.password
                   }
        print(payload)
        self.session.headers.update(self.headers)
        self.session.get(self.api['home'])
        self.session.post(self.api['login'], data=payload)
        account = self.session.get(self.api['account'])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(account.text, 'html.parser')
        try:
            if self.username == soup.find('p', {'class': 'name'}).string:
                print('successfully logged in')
            else:
                raise LoginError
        except:
            print('Login failed')
```

So when I say `test = pdAPI('username', 'password')` and then `test.login()` my session with the login info will be contained in the `test` object. Now I have another child class, which needs to make use of the `session` and the `api`.

Currently I have this:

```
class Video(object):
    def __init__(self, link=''):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Video, self).__init__()
            self.link = link

    def tags(self):
        g = self.session.get(self.link)
        print(g.text)
```

What I would like to do, not sure if it's possible, is to do something like this then:

```
video = test.Video(link='http://somelink.com')
```

Seeing as the `test` object already contains `session`. But it would already suffice to be able to use the session from `pdAPI` in `Video`.